# R: Patching a package function and reloading base libraries

Tags: r

Occasionally one wants to patch a function in a package, without recompiling the whole package.

For example, in Emacs ESS, the function `install.packages()` might get stuck if `tcltk` is not loaded. One might want to patch `install.packages()` in order to require  `tcltk` before installation and unload it after the package setup.

A `temp()` patched version of `install.packages()` might be:

```
## Get original args without ending NULL
temp=rev(rev(deparse(args(install.packages)))[-1]) 
temp=paste(paste(temp, collapse="\n"),
           ## Add code to load tcltk
           "{",
           "    wasloaded= 'package:tcltk' %in% search()",
           "    require(tcltk)",
           ## Add orginal body without braces
           paste(rev(rev(deparse(body(install.packages))[-1])[-1]), collapse="\n"),
           ## Unload tcltk if it was not loaded before by user
           "    if(!wasloaded) detach('package:tcltk', unload=TRUE)",
           "}\n",
           sep="\n")

## Eval patched function 
temp=eval(parse(text=temp))
# temp
```

Now we want to replace the original `install.packages()` and perhaps insert the code in `Rprofile`.

To this end it is worth nothing that:

```
getAnywhere("install.packages")
# A single object matching 'install.packages' was found
# It was found in the following places
#   package:utils
#   namespace:utils
# with value
#  
# ... install.packages() source follows (quite lengthy)
```

That is, the function is stored inside the package/namespace of `utils`. This environment  is sealed and therefore `install.packages()` should be unlocked before being replaced:

```
## Override original function
unlockBinding("install.packages", as.environment("package:utils"))
assign("install.packages", temp,  envir=as.environment("package:utils"))
unlockBinding("install.packages",  asNamespace("utils"))
assign("install.packages", temp,  envir=asNamespace("utils"))
rm(temp)
```

Using `getAnywhere()` again, we get:

```
getAnywhere("install.packages")
# A single object matching 'install.packages' was found
# It was found in the following places
#   package:utils
#   namespace:utils
# with value
#  
# ... the *new* install.packages() source follows
```

It seems that the patched function is placed in the right place.

Unfortunately, running it gives:

```
Error in install.packages(xxxxx) : 
  could not find function "getDependencies"
```

`getDependencies()` is a function inside the same `utils` package, but not exported; therefore it is not accessible outside its namespace.
Despite the output of `getAnywhere("install.packages")`, the patched `install.packages()` is still misplaced.

The problem is that we need to reload the `utils` library to obtain the desired effect, which also requires unloading other libraries importing it.

```
detach("package:stats", unload=TRUE)
detach("package:graphics", unload=TRUE)
detach("package:grDevices", unload=TRUE)
detach("package:utils", unload=TRUE)   
library(utils)
```

`install.packages()` works now.

Of course, we need to reload the other libraries too. Given the dependencies, using

```
library(stats)
```

should reload everything. But there is a problem when reloading the `graphics` library, at least on Windows:

```
library(graphics)
# Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
#   no such symbol C_contour in package path/to/library/graphics/libs/x64/graphics.dll
```

Which is the correct way of (re)loading the `graphics` library?

Comment: You lost me when describing the purpose of your example but I stopped reading when I saw eval(parse()).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Patching functions in packages is a low-level operation that should be avoided, because it may break internal assumptions of the execution environment and lead to unpredictable behavior/crashes. If there is a problem with tck/ESS (I didn't try to repeat that) perhaps it should be fixed or there may be a workaround. Particularly changing locked bindings is something to avoid.

If you really wanted to run some code at the start/end of say `install.packages`, you can use `trace`. It will do some of the low-level operations mentioned in the question, but the good part is you don't have to worry about fixing this whenever some new internals of R change.

```
trace(install.packages, 
    tracer=quote(cat("Starting install.packages\n")),
    exit=quote(cat("Ending install packages.\n"))
)
```

Replace `tracer` and `exit` accordingly - maybe `exit` is not needed anyway, maybe you don't need to unload the package. Still, `trace` is a very useful tool for debugging.

I am not sure if that will solve your problem - if it would work with ESS - but in general you can also wrap `install.packages` in a function you define say in your workspace:

```
install.packages <- function(...) {
    cat("Entry.\n")
    on.exit(cat("Exit.\n"))
    utils::install.packages(...)
}
```

This is the cleanest option indeed.

Comment: +1 I knew about trace, didn't think of it in this term. The problem with `install.package<- ...` is that it clutters the output of `ls()`